# How to display the data to table ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this ajax function and it

```
$("#save").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('addSocialWorker') }}',
            data: 
            {
                'name': $('#name').val(),
                'email': $('#email').val(),
                'password':$('#password').val(),
                'city_id': $("#city_id" ).val(),
                '_token': '{{ Session::token() }}'
            },
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data);
            },

            error: function(res)
            {
                if (res.status == 422) {
                    var data = res.responseJSON;

                    for (let i in data) {
                        showValidationErrors(i, data[i][0])
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Now, i want to display the newly inputted data into my table without loading the page. And i don't know how to do that in jquery. I don't know what to write in my success function. I'm really new to jquery and its functions and my time is running. Don't have time to read about jquery and stuff.

this is my table

```
<tbody id="usersTable">
                                    @foreach($data as $item)
                                    <tr class="item{{$item->user_id}}">
                                        <td>{{$item->Uname}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$item->city_name}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="edit-btn btn btn-warning btn-anim" data-id="{{$item->user_id}}" data-Uname="{{$item->Uname}}" data-email="{{$item->email}}" data-city_name="{{$item->city_name}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span class="btn-text">Edit</span></button>
                                            <button class="delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-anim" data-id="{{$item->user_id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span class="btn-text">delete</span></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

now i can add it already and it works and the validation but the problem is the displaying to table without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should word, i would recommend using Vue.js , it makes this easier once you get along with it

```js
var data = {
                'Uname': 'azezaeaz',
                'email': 'khhhh',
                'user_id':'1',
                'city_name': 'TUNIS',
            }; // TEST DATA (the will simulate data came from your php)

$("#save").click(function (e) { 
  
        $("#usersTable").prepend("<tr class='item" +data.user_id +"'><td>" + data.Uname + "</td><td>" + data.email + "</td><td>" + data.city_name + "</td><td><button class='edit-btn btn btn-warning btn-anim' data-id='" + data.user_id + "' data-Uname='" + data.Uname + "' data-email='" + data.email + "' data-city_name='" + data.city_name + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i><span class='btn-text'>Edit</span></button><button class='delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-anim' data-id='" + data.user_id + "'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i><span class='btn-text'>delete</span></button></td></tr>");



        });
```

```css
td {
  width : 20%; // nvm this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tbody id="usersTable">
   <tr class="item{{$item->user_id}}">
      <td>test</td>
      <td>aze</td>
      <td>zaea</td>
      <td>
         <button class="edit-btn btn btn-warning btn-anim" data-id="{{$item->user_id}}" data-Uname="{{$item->Uname}}" data-email="{{$item->email}}" data-city_name="{{$item->city_name}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span class="btn-text">Edit</span></button>
         <button class="delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-anim" data-id="{{$item->user_id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span class="btn-text">delete</span></button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="save" value="test">
```

Comment: Thank you sir. ok I'll get along with your tip

Comment: Hey i hard coded myself your code and studied it and I see this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token:

`$("#usersTable").append(
     "<tr class='item" + data.id +"'>
     <td>" + data.Uname + "</td>
     <td>" + data.email + "</td>
     </tr");`

Comment: Check my updated answer, everything works fine., if you still have an error pls share the exact out put and in which line